# How to write a shellscript date check that will not To run Except 3rd week sat, Sunday and 4th week Monday of the month

Tags: shell, scheduled-tasks

E.g. the schellscript will not run on april 18, 19 and 20 and then for may is 16, 17 and 18 and so on

Comment: Sounds easier to have the shellscript check at startup and exit immediately on the forbidden dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the weekday in numerical form from the date command using `date "+%w"`.
The output will be 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday etc.

You can get the day of the month using `date "+%d"`.  Subtract one from that and divide by 7; that will give you how many complete weeks there have been in the current month.

From there, it's just a simple bunch of if/then statements.  If you need more help actually implementing this, just ask.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to use cron for this kind of things, to separate the planned execution from what the script **really** does.

Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) on how to use cron.